# Can you debug an sbt build in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I have an sbt build that is giving me some problems. is there a way to debug it in IntelliJ?

Comment: Do you want to debug problems with the build process, or problems with the resulting compiled program?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add any java command line, including sbt commands, as a run/debug configuration. Open the menu "Run", "Edit Configurations", "+" (Add new configuration), choose "SBT Task" and fill the necessary parameters. For example, if you have a test that fails under "sbt testOnly", put `"testOnly package.ClassOfFailingTest"` into "Tasks" box.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch18s14.html :

> Set the SBT logging level in your build.sbt file with this setting:
>
> `logLevel := Level.Debug`

Does the increased log verbosity point to a problem?